# PHP MySQLi prepared statements - SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli

I have problems with my SELECT syntax.
Code:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT ? FROM `shop_items` WHERE `id` = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("si", $what, $itemsId);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($res);

$stmt->fetch();

echo $res;
```

When I want to select "name", it echo "name" instead of result from DB. How to solve it?

Comment: You **can't** do this => `SELECT ?`

Comment: You can't use a placeholder for the field name(s) in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you use question mark (?) after SELECT. It should be * symbol where you can select it all from 'shop_items'. You can try again with that.

Comment: @GigaWatt: You can't use `?` for a field name.

Comment: @GigaWatt Not after the `SELECT`.

Comment: *"It should be `*` symbol where you can select it all from 'shop_items'."* - Or choose actual column(s) name(s).

Answer (score 5):

Placeholder `?` can be used in prepared statement only in substitution of values, not for field names, table names or statement.

You're trying to use it for a field name.

You can build up your query string

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT " . $what . " FROM `shop_items` WHERE `id` = ?");
```

but you must be sure you can trust what's inside `$what` in order to avoid sql injection.

Otherwise you may get all fields

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `shop_items` WHERE `id` = ?");
```

Fetch results in an associative array (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) and then get only the field value pointed by `$what`