# News page doesn't fetch news_id automatically after using the GET methods

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

**Good Day All! Kindly help me check this code and make a correction if necessary. Thank You in Advance.**

```
$colname_newtable = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['news_id'])) {
  (int)$colname_newtable = $_GET['news_id'];
  }else{
    die('You must give a get parameter');

$mysql = new mysql("localhost", "root", "", "pgandb");
  $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM news_table WHERE news_id = ?");

//Binds the parameter as an integer.
$stmt->bind_param("i", $newsId);

//Executes the query
$stmt->execute();
//Binds the result (in your case only one row)
$stmt->bind_result($res);
//Fetches the result
$stmt->fetch();
//Display it
die(var_dump($res));

}

mysql_select_db($database_LocalPHPServer, $LocalPHPServer); 
$query_newtable = sprintf("SELECT * FROM news_table WHERE  news_id = $news_id ORDER BY news_id DESC", GetSQLValueString($colname_newtable, "int"));
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is. Also, you don't execute your query in this example, perhaps it's not complete?

Comment: The issue is that I want my news page to get the News ID from the table automatically instead of manually changing the New ID my self. This is what I have.

Comment: Please copy/paste all the code that is in the picture instead of posting a picture. Then, have you tried a `var_dump` of `$row_newtable`?

Comment: @ceejayoz my day has just brightened. Thank you for sharing that further tome of knowledge `:-)`

Comment: Please add a comment instead of rewriting your comment each time. I have no notification when the question is updated.
I'll update my answer to show you a more complete example.

Comment: What URL are you typing in your browser? Without informations I can't help you..

Comment: You'd read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Below an example that is very similar to yours. You can see the method calls in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24002121/4932315)

```
<?php
//file.php

$newsId = -1;

if (!isset($_GET['news_id'])) {
    die('The news_id parameter is missing');
}

$newsId = (int)$_GET['news_id'];

//Initializes the database connection using OOP.
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "myUsername", "myPassword", "databaseName");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = ?");
//Binds the parameter as an integer.
$stmt->bind_param("i", $newsId);
//Executes the query
$stmt->execute();
//Binds the result (in your case only one row)
$stmt->bind_result($res);
//Fetches the result
$stmt->fetch();
//Display it
die(var_dump($res));
```

To test this file you can open it in your Web browser, for example `http://localhost/file.php` and it should print the message in the `die`. But if you type `http://localhost/file.php?news_id=2` you should see the content.
I've tested on my local machine after creating a database and a table called both `news`. I let you change the database and table name.